# Unsure why Synechococcus moves at angle in cuvette

Tags: bacteriology, experiment, heat

I'd really appreciate your help. I'm working with *Synechococcus*. In my experiment, I have *Synechococcus* in a solution of milli-Q water. I illuminated it with a focused white light through a pinhole and observed it using a CCD camera. The *Synechococcus* flows downward, which I think is due to gravity. But, in time, the *Synechococcus* flows downwards at an angle. Is this due to heat convection? If it is heat convection, it's strange that it sometimes stops flowing. The only visible motion seems to be Brownian motion.

Thank you your help!